# Get attached media only

Tags: wp-query, attachments, exclude

I am using wp_query to get uploaded medias. Everything is working fine, but wp_query will return the medias with no post attached.  This is not what I wanted. How can I exclude the unattached media from the wp_query?

This is my query arguments look like:

```
 $args = array(
  'post_type' => 'attachment',
  'post_status' => 'inherit',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  );
  $attachemnt = new WP_Query($args);
```

Is there any argument that can use for exclude the unattached media in wp_query class?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All media (somewhat incorrectly) in the `$wpdb->posts` table will be "attachments" whether actually attached or not. "Attachments" that are actually attached will have a `post_parent` other than 0, so what you need are all of the attachments that have a 0 in the `post_parent` column, if I understand you.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'attachment',
  'post_status' => 'inherit',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'post_parent__not_in' = array(0)
);
$attachment = new WP_Query($args);

var_dump($attachment->posts);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ( $post->post_type == **'post type name'** && $post->post_status == 'publish' ) {
    $attachments = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'exclude'     => get_post_thumbnail_id()
    ) );

    if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
            $class = "post-attachment mime-" . sanitize_title( $attachment->post_mime_type );
            $thumbimg = wp_get_attachment_link( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail-size', true );
            echo '<li class="' . $class . ' data-design-thumbnail">' . $thumbimg . '</li>';
        }

    }
}
```

?>

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But this is not i want, actually I don't have the 'post_parent' in the first place.

Comment: Please explain _why_ this answer is helpful.

Comment: @kaiser, do you mean me? No, I don't think this answer is helpful.

Comment: No, I was referring to @Chetan as he just posted code without explanation of what it does and how it is supposed to fix your issue.