# Unable to get all the Posts Attachments

Tags: posts, attachments

I want to retrieve all the image attachments from a posts and render it in a gallery. Some how the number attachments which is being returned is only one even tough the posts contains multiple image attachments. Strangely some of the attachments which are beings returned are  not even present in the posts. Below is the function which I am using to get the attchments

```
function get_attchments($num=1){
  $output = '';
  if (has_post_thumbnail() && $num == 1){
      $output = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()));
    }else {
      $attachments = get_posts(array(
          'post_type' => 'attachment',
          'posts_per_page' => $num,
          'exclude'     => get_post_thumbnail_id(),
          'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
      ));

  if ($attachments && $num == 1){
          foreach ($attachments as $attachment){
              $output = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID);
            }
  }else if($attachments && $num > 1){       
          $output = $attachments;
  }
  wp_reset_postdata();
}
 return $output;
}
```

I am calling the function as below

```
while(have_posts()){
                    the_post();
                    $def_class='twigs';
                    set_query_var('lighter_def_post_class', 'twigs');
                    get_template_part('template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
                  }
```

And this is the code for contenet-gallery.php

```
$attachments = get_attchments(7);          
    foreach( $attachments as $attachment ){
        //I am rendering the images out here
    }
```

I've been with this issues since long. Thank you

Comment: And how do you call this function?

Comment: I have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have an easier time if you used: `$wpdb`

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = 'posts'; // change this to your post-table name, it may be something different.
$values = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name where post_type = attachment");
foreach ($values as $value){
  print_r($value);
}
```

If you're seeing unexpected values, then you'll need to figure out if there's anything different about the unexpected values.

By that I mean, are the unexpected values coming from posts which have been deleted? Or attachments that have been moved to the trash but not completely removed? Maybe have a poke around and see if you can find the unexpected attachments and see if you can delete them.

To troubleshoot this further, it would be good to know what's happening in the $wp_query outside of where you're calling this function. using `global $wp_query; var_dump($wp_query); exit;` can tell you more.

Comment: The unexpected attachments are the images which are being removed from the posts but not permanently .

Comment: A custom query could help, the `'post_parent__not_in' = array(0)` looks promising.  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139516/get-attached-media-only You'll want to use wp_query, not get_posts (general rule of thumb)